# Java : JSONObject.put looped gives wrong order?

Tags: java, json

Today I started writing a simple parser for a log file. I want to take the log file and transform it into a simple json structure.

The log file is consistent and has 3 main parts (example below):

- the timestamp [23 digits]
- the code [4 digits]
- the payload [variable digits]

**Example log**

```
2018-07-25T08:47:16,094,164f,test1
2018-07-25T08:47:18,163,1678,test2
2018-07-25T08:47:19,501,1662,test3
2018-07-25T08:47:21,278,1634,test4
2018-07-25T08:47:23,347,1632,test5
2018-07-25T08:47:24,686,1665,test6
2018-07-25T08:47:26,463,1678,test7
2018-07-25T08:47:28,533,1678,test8
2018-07-25T08:47:29,877,1632,test9
2018-07-25T08:47:31,687,1632,test10
```

From this I wanted to create a JSON file that would incorporate well the information inside. This is what I came up with (using `org.json.JSONObject` library).

```java
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("file.log"));

String line = null;
String timestamp = null;
String eventCode = null;
String payload = null;

JSONObject codePayload = new JSONObject();
JSONObject finalString = new JSONObject();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    line = reader.readLine();

    timestamp = line.substring(0, 23);
    eventCode = line.substring(24, 28);
    payload = line.substring(29, line.length());

    codePayload.put("ID", eventCode);
    codePayload.put("PL", payload);
    finalString.put(timestamp, codePayload);

    codePayload = new JSONObject();
  }
  System.out.println(finalString.toString());
```

This little snippet should work quite well (don't mind the for) and it kinda does. It creates the JSON file according to the string I give it but it puts then in a strange order, see below.

```
{
  "2018-07-25T08:47:24,686": {
    "ID": "1665",
    "PL": "test6"
  },
  "2018-07-25T08:47:29,877": {
    "ID": "1632",
    "PL": "test9"
  },
  "2018-07-25T08:47:31,687": {
    "ID": "1632",
    "PL": "test10"
  },
  "2018-07-25T08:47:16,094": {
    "ID": "164f",
    "PL": "test1"
  },
  "2018-07-25T08:47:21,278": {
    "ID": "1634",
    "PL": "test4"
  },
  "2018-07-25T08:47:18,163": {
    "ID": "1678",
    "PL": "test2"
  },
  "2018-07-25T08:47:23,347": {
    "ID": "1632",
    "PL": "test5"
  },
  "2018-07-25T08:47:28,533": {
    "ID": "1678",
    "PL": "test8"
  },
  "2018-07-25T08:47:19,501": {
    "ID": "1662",
    "PL": "test3"
  },
  "2018-07-25T08:47:26,463": {
    "ID": "1678",
    "PL": "test7"
  }
}
```

As you can clearly see it places the objects in the wrong order and I really don't know why. If someone has the slightest idea on how this problem could occur please comment below. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `JSONObject` is a subclass of `HashMap` and there is not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time. You're probably better off using a list or other kind of data.

Comment: @ChatterOne JSONObject is not a subclass of HashMap , see https://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The org.json.JSONObject is un-ordered, so better to use javax.json.JSONObject OR if you are using org.json library, use the org.json.JSONArray to store the timestamps in order.

Comment: Very good explanation but now I find myself in another problem: since I never used this class before and it seems to require a `JsonValue`, how do I convert my `Strings` to that? Thanks again for the clear answer!

Comment: Don't read the last comment, you clarified very well the problem and I solved it thanks to your advice. I used the JSONArray method but just because it's easier for now, maybe if I have some time later I will change it to use the other library. Anyway thanks a lot!